# Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger

Tags: .net, wpf, datatrigger

I've created a UserControl, similar to the following:

```
<UserControl>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel x:Name="Launch" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <!-- Children here -->
        </StackPanel>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleLaunch" IsChecked="False" Content="Launch"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I've been trying to use a DataTrigger to make the 'Launch' StackPanel become visible when the ToggleButton is checked, and remain collapsed otherwise.  However, at runtime I get an error stating "Failed object initialization (ISupportInitialize.EndInit). Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger".  I've tried adding it to the trigger collection of the UserControl and StackPanel with no success.  My trigger XAML looks like the following:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ToggleLaunch, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Launch" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

DataTriggers are meant for Style, ControlTemplate and DataTemplate per the [MSDN Docs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx)

Solution was to use an EventTrigger as the error message indicated.  My solution was the following:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="LaunchButtons">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                        Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="LaunchButtons">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                        Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
 </EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 58):

From [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx), as per the (slightly paraphrased) answer from Richard C. McGuire:

> DataTriggers can be used with XML tags *Style*, *ControlTemplate* and *DataTemplate*

For example, if you attempt to add a trigger to a `TextBlock`, it will generate this error:

> *Error: Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger*

Why? A `Trigger` can only be placed inside a `Style`, `ControlTemplate` or `DataTemplate`, and we are trying to place it directly inside a `TextBlock`.

In this case, the fix is easy: **just wrap the trigger in a style**, then place this style inside the `TextBlock`, and the error will disappear.

Here is the error-generating XAML *before* the fix:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Hello" Text="{Binding Hello, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <TextBlock.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Hello}" Value="GoGreen">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
      </DataTrigger>
  </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Here is the XAML *after* the fix:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Hello" Text="{Binding Hello, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Hello}" Value="GoGreen">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Here is a sample screenshot showing that if we enter `GoGreen`, the text goes green:

[image]

... and if we enter something else, the text defaults to red:

[image]

There is loads of free material on the web about WPF triggers, and all of them do a reasonably good job of explaining the concept, and [this page was the one that made the penny drop for me](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/).

Comment: If you already have a *Style* resource set on your UI control (as it happened to me), in order to avoid further errors, just turn that into the base of the local style having *DataTrigger*. As in: `<TextBlock.Style> <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource YourPreviousStyleResource}"> <Style.Triggers> <DataTrigger ...` HTH

Answer (score 5):

You could also bind the Visibility in your stackpanel to the IsChecked property in the ToggleButton.  You would need to use a custom ValueConverter.  Here is one I found online:

```
/// <summary>  
/// WPF/Silverlight ValueConverter : Convert boolean to XAML Visibility
/// </summary>  
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        value != null && (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This may be hopelessly outdated, but the following works for me. It might help people running into the problem with: "Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger"

```
<Control>
  <Control.Template>
    <ControlTemplate >

      <!-- Design -->
      <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Name="CollapseControl" Content="Show" IsChecked="False" />
        <Label Name="CollapseTarget" Content="MyContent" Visibility="Collapsed" />
      </StackPanel>

      <!-- Triggers -->
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers >
        <Trigger SourceName="CollapseControl" Property="IsChecked" Value="True" >
          <Setter TargetName="CollapseTarget" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    </ControlTemplate>
  </Control.Template>
</Control>
```

Encapsulating "what you want to control" inside a Control object allows you to use the Control.Template to use any trigger you want. This way you can use (data)triggers directly in your XAML where you want to without defining a static style or a completely new UserControl.