# How do I properly animate my Border to move to the right

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I have this style that targets my ToggleButton, and I am trying to change the `HorizontalAlignment` of the border named `ThumbCircle` from Left to Right, I did read that changing that property is not as easy as just changing the value, I'm going to have to do some sort of LayoutTransform, however that didn't seem to work, when I click my button nothing happens, it doesnt move.

So my question is, how do I get the `ThumbCircle` to move to the right side of the `Border` that it's currently placed a.

```
<Style x:Key="MyToggleButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

        <Style.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="Color.MyBtn.PrimaryColor">#2ecc71</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Color.MyBtn.SecondaryColor">#27ae60</Color>
        </Style.Resources>


        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Width="50" Height="12" Background="White" CornerRadius="6">

                        </Border>

                        <Border Width="25"
                                Background="#2ecc71"
                                CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                x:Name="ThumbCircle">
                            <Border.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <!-- Dont forget easing -->
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbCircle" To="10" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>

                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Border.Triggers>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why nothing is showing up**

The reason why you don't see anything moving is because you're targeting the `(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)` property of your `ThumbCircle`, but it doesn't have any value set to its `LayoutTransform` property.

If you add this to your `ThumbCircle` `Border`:

```xml
    <Border.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform/>
    </Border.LayoutTransform>
```

Then you will see something happening. But you'll see a scaling, not a translation! What you want is to translate from one side to the other.

**The intuitive fix doesn't work...**

The easiest way would have been to first replace the `LayoutTransform` with a `RenderTransform` and the `ScaleTransform` with a `TranslateTransform` like this:

```xml
    <Border.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="MyTranslate"/>
    </Border.LayoutTransform>
```

Then give a name to your `Grid` like this:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    ...
</Grid>
```

And then animating the `X` property of the `TranslateTransform` from `0` to your `Grid.ActualWidth` like this:

```xml
<!-- This won't run -->
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="MyTranslate" To="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
```

But it is not possible to achieve this as it is not possible to set a `Binding` on any property of an `Animation` when used like this, because WPF makes some optimizations that prevent this [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669750/wpf-animation-cannot-freeze-this-storyboard-timeline-tree-for-use-across-thread).

**A XAML-intensive way to do it**

So a way to do it is to define proxy elements whose property we animate from `0` to `1` ,and we make the multiplication with `MyGrid.ActualWidth` at another location.

So your whole XAML style becomes:

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

    <Style.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="Color.MyBtn.PrimaryColor">#2ecc71</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Color.MyBtn.SecondaryColor">#27ae60</Color>
        <!-- Aded some converters here -->
        <views:MultiMultiplierConverter x:Key="MultiMultiplierConverter"></views:MultiMultiplierConverter>
        <views:OppositeConverter x:Key="OppositeConverter"></views:OppositeConverter>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid">
                    <Border Width="50" Height="12" Background="Red" CornerRadius="6">

                    </Border>
                    <Border Width="25"
                        Background="#2ecc71"
                        CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        x:Name="ThumbCircle">
                        <Border.Resources>
                            <!-- Proxy object whose X property gets animated from 0 to 1. -->
                            <!-- Could be any DependencyObject with a property of type double. -->
                            <TranslateTransform x:Key="unusedKey" x:Name="Proxy"></TranslateTransform>
                        </Border.Resources>
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <!-- Main translation to move from one side of the grid to the other -->
                                <TranslateTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform.X>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiMultiplierConverter}" ConverterParameter="2">
                                            <Binding ElementName="Proxy" Path="X"></Binding>
                                            <Binding ElementName="ContainerGrid" Path="ActualWidth"></Binding>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TranslateTransform.X>
                                </TranslateTransform>

                                <!-- Secondary translation to adjust to the actual width of the object to translate -->
                                <TranslateTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform.X>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiMultiplierConverter}" ConverterParameter="2">
                                            <Binding ElementName="Proxy" Path="X"></Binding>
                                            <Binding ElementName="ThumbCircle" Path="ActualWidth" Converter="{StaticResource OppositeConverter}"></Binding>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TranslateTransform.X>
                                </TranslateTransform>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <Border.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- Dont forget easing -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Proxy" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Border.Triggers>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And you would need to define two `IValueConverter` to perform some basic arithmetic operations on your `Binding`s:

One for multiplying all supplied values in a `MultiBinding`:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Defines a converter which multiplies all provided values.
/// The given parameter indicates number of arguments to multiply.
/// </summary>
public class MultiMultiplierConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        double result = 1;
        int count = int.Parse((string)parameter);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            result *= (double)values[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
    }
}
```

And one to multiply the input by `-1`:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Defines a converter which multiplies the provided value by -1
/// </summary>
public class OppositeConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return (dynamic)value * -1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
    }
}
```

This is not an elegant way but it works!

**How to implement back and forth animations?**

So far we managed to animate the thumb to the right, on click. But that's not the whole point, is it?

What we are templating is a `ToggleButton`: at every click, an animation to the opposite side should be triggered. More exactly, whenever the `IsChecked` property gets `True`, we should trigger an animation to the right, and whenever the `IsChecked` property gets `False`, we should trigger an animation to the left.

This is possible by adding some `Trigger` objects in the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` collection. The `Trigger` shall be hooked to the `IsChecked` property (which we have no control over) and listen to its changes. We can specify an `EnterAction` which is our animation to the right, and an `ExitAction` which is our animation to the left.

The full `Style` becomes:

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

    <Style.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="Color.MyBtn.PrimaryColor">#2ecc71</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Color.MyBtn.SecondaryColor">#27ae60</Color>
        <!-- Aded some converters here -->
        <views:MultiMultiplierConverter x:Key="MultiMultiplierConverter"></views:MultiMultiplierConverter>
        <views:OppositeConverter x:Key="OppositeConverter"></views:OppositeConverter>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <!-- Animation to the right -->
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!-- Dont forget easing -->
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Proxy" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                        <!-- Animation to the left -->
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!-- Dont forget easing -->
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Proxy" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid">
                    <Border Width="50" Height="12" Background="Red" CornerRadius="6">

                    </Border>
                    <Border Width="25"
                Background="#2ecc71"
                CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                x:Name="ThumbCircle">
                        <Border.Resources>
                            <!-- Proxy object whose X property gets animated from 0 to 1. -->
                            <!-- Could be any DependencyObject with a property of type double. -->
                            <TranslateTransform x:Key="unusedKey" x:Name="Proxy"></TranslateTransform>
                        </Border.Resources>
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <!-- Main translation to move from one side of the grid to the other -->
                                <TranslateTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform.X>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiMultiplierConverter}" ConverterParameter="2">
                                            <Binding ElementName="Proxy" Path="X"></Binding>
                                            <Binding ElementName="ContainerGrid" Path="ActualWidth"></Binding>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TranslateTransform.X>
                                </TranslateTransform>

                                <!-- Secondary translation to adjust to the actual width of the object to translate -->
                                <TranslateTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform.X>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiMultiplierConverter}" ConverterParameter="2">
                                            <Binding ElementName="Proxy" Path="X"></Binding>
                                            <Binding ElementName="ThumbCircle" Path="ActualWidth" Converter="{StaticResource OppositeConverter}"></Binding>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TranslateTransform.X>
                                </TranslateTransform>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note that this `Trigger` is only accepted inside a `ControlTemplate.Triggers` collection, it is not possible to put such a `Trigger` in the original `Border.Triggers` collection, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836703/triggers-collection-members-must-be-of-type-eventtrigger).

Comment: That's a great answer! Is it possible to make it reverse the animation when IsChecked is false?

Comment: I edited:) honestly this is one of the most frustrating issue with WPF, having to find a way to make things work and that makes sense...

Comment: That's really impressive! I really like your approach! I do however think Microsoft should allow binding in Storyboards without having the freeze issue. Thank you so much! I'm learning so much from this!

Comment: Is it possible to change the background of the "Red" border when IsChecked is true?

Comment: Yes. If you can't find by yourself, you should definitely ask another question on SO :) but I'm sure there are already plenty of answers to that one.